# Assigning charAtIndex to stringWithCharacters gives invalid cast warning and bad access error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I'm trying to grab firstname and lastname from firstname+lastname.

```
int loop=0;
NSMutableString *firstname = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
 NSMutableString *fullName = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Anahita+Havewala"];

for (loop = 0; ([fullName characterAtIndex:loop]!='+'); loop++) {
    [firstname appendString:[NSString stringWithCharacters:(const unichar *)[fullName characterAtIndex:loop] length:1]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",firstname);
```

I tried typecasting from unichar to const unichar* because characterAtIndex returns a unichar but stringWithCharacters accepts a const unichar.

This causes a cast from smaller integer type warning and the app crashes (bad access) when this line is encountered.

Why are string operations so complicated in Objective C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
NSMutableString *firstname = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSMutableString *fullName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Anahita+Havewala"];

for (NSUInteger loop = 0; ([fullName characterAtIndex:loop]!='+'); loop++) {
    unichar myChar = [fullName characterAtIndex:loop];
    [firstname appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", myChar]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", firstname);
```

Comment: Always happy to help! Glad it helped you :)!

Comment: Not sure why I got a down vote here. Please post a reason for down voting!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get first name and last using [componentsSeparatedByString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) method.

```
NSMutableString *fullName = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Anahita+Havewala"];
NSArray *components = [fullName componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
NSString *firstName = components[0];
NSString *lastName  = components[1];
```

**Note:** You need to do proper array bounds check. Also you can use [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/) for the same purpose.

Comment: How would I do an array bounds check? I don't know how many characters would be before the '+' or after. And if I need to find that out, I'd have to use characterAtIndex.